# Escaping of double quotes in rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, escaping, double-quotes

I have recently ungraded to rails 3.2 and getting a problem with the escaping of double quotes.
I have a string like this

```
options = "class=\"input\" disabled=\"disabled\" value=\"[{\"id\"=>\"514aede7\",    \"label\"=>\"document\"}, {\"id\"=>\"3a55e040\", \"label\"=>\"license\"}]\""
```

and i use this as part of my list options as in one of my helper functions

```
"<ol #{options}></ol>"
```

but since i have upgraded to rails 3.2 and ruby 1.9 my list is floating in html view 
it takes

```
value="[{"
```

and closes ol's opening tag with

```
id">
```

and rest of the information in value field just floats.

```
""514aede7", "label"=>"document"}, {"id"=>"3a55e040", "label"=>"license"}]">"
```

Can someone help me understand whats the root cause of this as I was not having same problem with rails 3.0 and ruby 1.8

Comment: Try "<ol '#{options}' ></ol>"

Comment: that doesn't work but if I use value = '[{\"id\"=>\"514aede7\",    \"label\"=>\"document\"}, {\"id\"=>\"3a55e040\", \"label\"=>\"license\"}]\"' i.e single quotes instead of escaped double quotes that works. But I want to know why it is not working now as it was working previously.

Answer (score 1):

Try `"<ol #{raw(options)}></ol>"`